# Inserting form data and adding 1 day

Tags: php, pdo

I have a function that inserts into a users table, I want to know if it is possible to  -1 day from the "dob" and insert into reminder column through the function

```
public function AddUser($email, $name, $dob)
{
    try {
        $db = DB();
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(email, name, dob, reminder) VALUES (:email, :name, :dob, :reminder)");
        $query->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("dob", $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("reminder", $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $query->execute();
        return $db->lastInsertId();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do with this line to do it on INSERT

Something along the lines of

```
   $query->bindParam("reminder", $dob DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)); PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

If this is not possible could you please give me some pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youn should use the :remainder in mysql date_add  function eg:

```
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(email, name, dob, reminder) 
             VALUES (:email, :name, :dob, DATE_ADD(:reminder, INTERVAL -1 DAY) )");
    $query->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("dob", $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("reminder", $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Hi, Its my first post and not letting me vote as answered, cant see the tick under the number anyways, I will keep checking back

Comment: Managed to do it :o)